# Multithreading Kinect frame analysis

Tags: multithreading, backgroundworker, kinect

I'm trying to use a backgroundworker to multithread some heavy processing of Kinect skeleton frames.

However, when I call the CoordinateMapper of the sensor in my backgroundworker, I get the FailedQI exeption, HRESULT : 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE).

From my understanding so far, it seems to be because I'm accessing a resource which is not initialized in my backgroundworker.

The code causing the exception to happen:

```
protected static Point SkeletonPointToScreen(SkeletonPoint skelpoint)
    {
        KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensorProvider.ProvideSensor();

        ColorImagePoint colorPoint = sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(skelpoint, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
        return new Point(colorPoint.Y, colorPoint.X);
    }
```

I don't understand how to overcome this problem. I tried to send the CoordinateMapper object as a parameter to my backgroundworker but without success.